# How do I make sure a user uses at least one file upload control to upload a file before redirecting from a view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file-upload

I have a view with about 20 file upload controls, each one is tied to a `HttpPostedFileBase`on a view model.

```
@*APPLICATION LETTER TO CBN*@
<div class="row col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.CbnApplicationLetter, "APPLICATION LETTER TO CBN", new { @class = "control-label, col-md-12" })
        <div class="col-md-12">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CbnApplicationLetter, new { type = "file", @class = "form-control", @id = "cbnLetter", @name = "cbnLetter" })
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@*APPLICATION TO MINISTRY OF AGRICULTURE*@
<div class="row col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.MinistryOfAgricApplication, "APPLICATION TO MINISTRY OF AGRICULTURE", new { @class = "control-label, col-md-12" })
        <div class="col-md-12">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MinistryOfAgricApplication, new { type = "file", @class = "form-control", @id = "agricMin", @name = "agricMin" })
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row" style="padding-bottom:20px;">
@*APPROVAL LETTER FROM NCAA*@
<div class="row col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.MinistryOfAgricApplication, "APPROVAL LETTER FROM NCAA", new { @class = "control-label, col-md-12" })
        <div class="col-md-12">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.NCCAAApprovalLetter, new { type = "file", @class = "form-control", @id = "ncaaLetter", @name = "ncaaLetter" })
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The solution I am working towards is one in which end-users have to upload at least one file using one of the file upload controls on the view.
They can upload using all of them or just use one, but the condition is that the user must use at least one file upload before they can leave the view.
I can include my controller and view-model code if required.
I don't know how to do this, and any help/suggestions will be appreciated.
I would also like to do this validation on both the client and server side.

Comment: In the simplest case you just have to write some controller code which checks each input in turn and invalidates the model if none of them contain a file. Likewise you can write a JS method to loop through them and do the same on the client before submitting the form. If you want something more sophisticated, have you researched the MVC validation framework and how to add custom methods to it?

Comment: you have an extra `</div>` by the way.. look at the fixed formatted markup I corrected for you